# Unable to access disk space in Windows

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-10, disk-management

I have installed Windows 10 in external HDD for my Mac Book and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237915/unable-to-boot-windows-10-from-bootcamp-external-hdd) is the steps followed.

When I installed windows in bootcamp, I have selected only 30GB space and restored to external 1TB hard disk. Now unable to access the remaining space in Windows. Now how to get that space for use?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking a question?

Comment: @joeqwerty yes, my bad missed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to extend the filesystem.

list the volumes
DISKPART> list volume

select the volume which does not show all the space available
DISKPART> select volume [x]

DISKPART> extend filesystem

This is based on information from the post below regarding virtual machines but it may help:

https://blog.mrpol.nl/2013/08/16/after-partition-extend-file-system-displays-wrong-disk-size-in-windows/